# Offline web application CRM using Laravel

Tags: web-services, laravel, server, localhost, local-storage

Guys I have **Offline Laravel CRM** that will manage part in a company.

This project will be only on **one** PC in the company and it shouldn't be online or on any other PC.

> Problem

I don't want to make the employee that uses this CRM to open **XAMPP** or any other programs to use the server then open the browser and start typing localhost/myLaravelCRM.

I want a program that the employee press and open the Server and the browser on the tab **Automatically**.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Install a web server (Apache or nginx), PHP, MySQL (or you could use SQLite) as services that start with OS. You'll find a lot of tutorials, especially for Linux. Then just set `localhost` or any other alias like `crm.app` as browser's home page. Then a user will just need to open a browser and he'll be able to work with Laravel CRM.